# JSF Duplicate Id issue in Alfresco webclient

Tags: jsf, duplicates, alfresco

I am using myfaces 1.1.8 and Alfresco 3.3.5
Even after giving id for all the JSF component in browse.jsp page i am facing duplicate id exception.

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: duplicate Id for a component browse:browse-col9"

This id is not repeated anywhere still it gives duplicate exception. Exception comes randomly.

Please let me know how can i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you've bound the component to a session or application scoped bean using `binding` and the view where the component is located is subject to dynamic changes (when components are dynamically added/removed).

You would then need to bind it to a request scoped bean instead, or to look for an alternative way for the `binding` or the dynamic nature of the view.

Comment: bean is session scoped bean which is used in binding, i cannot change that as alfresco product has done that coding. we don't dynamically add or remove components. Is there any other approach. Same code worked with myfaces1.1.5. In stack trace i could see exception is trown from AjaxStateManager class which is of richfaces, we are using richfaces-3.1 can that be any issue?